# 'Error: is.request(y) is not TRUE' error when using RGA library (R CRAN) to fetch data from Google analytics via the API

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

After a library update from `RGA` library to 0.2.4, 
the below error message is returned by R when I fetch data:

> Error: is.request(y) is not TRUE

It happens when using RStudio or in batch mode.

This is my previously working code:

```
firstdate(profile.id = profile_ID, token = ga_token_RGA)
```

and

```
get_ga(profile.id = profile_ID , 
    start.date = "500daysAgo", 
    end.date = "yesterday", 
    metrics = "ga:users,ga:sessions", 
    dimensions = "ga:date", 
    token = ga_token_RGA)
```

As it seems to be httr related, I tried to devolute httr using:

```
remove.packages("httr")
install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/httr/httr_0.6.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

But RGA required version 1

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>   namespace ‘httr’ 0.6.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RGA’

And finally:
Here is a traceback() an a sessionInfo()

```
library("RGA")
profile_ID <- ******************
first_date <- as.character(firstdate(profile.id = profile_ID, token = ga_token_RGA))
```

> Error: is.request(y) is not TRUE

```
traceback()

16: stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(r), "%s is not TRUE", "%s are not all TRUE"), ch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
15: stopifnot(is.request(x), is.request(y))  
14: f(init, x[[i]])  
13: Reduce(request_combine, list(...))  
12: c.request(req, token$sign(req$method, req$url))  
11: c(req, token$sign(req$method, req$url))  
10: request_prepare(req)  
9: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)  
8: GET(url, query = query, accept_json(), config)  
7: get_response(type = type, path = path, query = query, token = token)  
6: get_data(type = type, query = query, token = token)  
5: get_report(type = "ga", query = query, token = token)  
4: get_ga(profile.id = profile.id, start.date = "2005-01-01", end.date = "today",metrics = "ga:sessions", dimensions = "ga:date", filters = "ga:sessions>0",max.results = 1L, token = token)  
3: withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))  
2: suppressWarnings(get_ga(profile.id = profile.id, start.date = "2005-01-01", end.date = "today", metrics = "ga:sessions", dimensions = "ga:date", filters = "ga:sessions>0", max.results = 1L, token = token))  
1: firstdate(profile.id = profile_ID, token = ga_token_RGA)


sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)  
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
Running under: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)  
locale:  
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C  
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
attached base packages:  
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base other attached packages:  
[1] RGA_0.2.4  
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  
[1] httr_1.0.0 R6_2.1.1 magrittr_1.5 tools_3.2.2 curl_0.9.3 Rcpp_0.12.1 stringi_0.5-5  
[8] jsonlite_0.9.17 stringr_1.0.0 httpuv_1.3.3
```

Comment: Your code works for me with `RGA` 0.2.4 from CRAN. Which packages have been updated with `RGA`? Can you post more details on the [bug tracker](https://github.com/artemklevtsov/RGA/issues) (include `traceback()`)?

Comment: Seems this error related with `httr` 1.0.0 update. But I can't reproduce it under Archlinux and Windows 10.

Comment: unfortunately I do a rough >update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)

Comment: This error is not related with the `RGA` package. Try ask on the `httr` bug tracker.